# Ocaml : Thread.delay not working as I expected

Tags: multithreading, class, ocaml, process

I am developping a small Anti-Missile Simulator for a Class Project.

The Idea is to have different processes/threads comunicating with each other.

I started working on the Missile Laucher application. Its missile has to be a thread.

So this is the start code I made:

```
open Missile;;

(* Name of the Station *)
let launcher_name = "Pacific";;

(* Gravitational Constant *)
let g = 9.8;;

(* Temporal Reference *)
let time = ref 0.0;;

(* Calculates the next position in time of the missile *)
let calculate_position () = 
  let nX = 10.0 *. !time and nY = (0.5) *. g**2.0 in (nX,nY);;

(* Launches the thread missile and updates its position *)
let launch mis = 
  while true do 

    let pos = mis#position () in 
    Printf.printf "%s\n" pos;


    let (a,b) = calculate_position () in
    mis#moveto (a,b);
    time := !time +. 1.0;

    (* Why isnt this working? *)
    Thread.delay 0.25 

  done;;



(* test function *)
let launchMissile () = 
  Printf.printf "Launch Station %s launched a missile. \n" launcher_name;
  let mis  = new missile "Test" 1 "USA" in
  let t1 = Thread.create launch mis in
  Thread.join t1;;



launchMissile ();;
```

After doing this I wanted to test my CalculatePosition function by printing the values over time.

But without a pause or wait they print out too fast, obviously. So I thought about delay the  thread 0.25 s in each of the while iteration.

What am I doing wrong? I tried so many different things. Its only the Thread.delay function that it is behaving strange.

Can I do this ?

If you could help it would be great, I have ran out of thought on this... and started rereading all the books I have here on Ocaml.

If it is also important for you to analyze the problem here is my Missile Class:

```
class missile name id owner = 
object
  val mutable name = name;
  val id = id;
  val owner = owner;
  val mutable x:float = 0.0
  val mutable y:float = 0.0
  method get_x = x
  method get_y = y
  method get_point = (x,y)
  method moveto (a,b) = x <- a; y <- b
  method rmoveto (dx, dy) = x <- x +. dx ; y <- y +. dy
  method to_string () = "( " ^ "I am Missile " ^ (string_of_int id) ^ " and my owner is   " ^ (owner) ^ ")";
  method position () = "(" ^ (string_of_float x) ^ "," ^ (string_of_float y) ^ ")";
  method distance () = sqrt (x*.x +. y*.y)
end;;
```

Thank you

Comment: The thread creation code is on the post, on the launchMissile function.

This is the compile command:
ocamlc -o enemy -thread unix.cma threads.cma missile.cmo enemy.ml

There is no error, the only problem is that it doesn't print what it is supposed.

Whithout the Thread.delay it does the print, with it it doesn't it just stalls.

I don't use anymore code. If you need anything else tell me! 

Its really getting me crazy

Comment: just a voodoo guess: add flush_all (); before you call to Thread.delay.

Comment: Well that worked! Do you want to add a answer to explain it? Why would that work? Anyway Thank you! Im really curious

Comment: @JoãoBastos my bad, I got confused with the scrollbar on the code section.

Comment: No problem, I didn't know it would do that also! But its working, althought I still don't know why!

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot of sense and know I see why it solves it. Thank you so much! That was really helpful!

Comment: I don't really have much to add to didierc's answer. So maybe he should get add his useful explanation as an answer. Anyway, you're welcome.

Comment: yes I will write all this an the answer to the problem. Thank all of you for the help

Comment: If you want to make the answer I will delete this one, didierc.
I just made it to not leave this unanswered!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Printf.*` functions are buffered (because of formatting features I suppose), while `print_*` and `prerr_*` are not. If you replace your `printf` by `print_endline`, you will see your output happening as expected, without having to `flush` the buffers.

So this has nothing to do with buffer contentions or concurrent accesses as I originally stated, but just plain internal (not system) buffering.

A few remarks in passing : you don't need to put semi-colon at the end of methods (though the grammar accepts it). Also, parentheses around expressions are superfluous between `^` operators. Both are a matter of style I guess.

Enjoy OCaml!

Answer (score 2):

As answered by didierc:

"Concurrent accesses to console output streams is always a problem. Flushing the buffers is the usual remedy, Otherwise data stay in the buffers and may never reach the console before the program terminates. This problem occurs when several process or threads write to the same terminal, or when a single process output to several streams all connected to the same terminal (like stdout and stderr)"

So you should do this by adding flush_all ();; before the call to Thread.delay

(Thank you for you answer!)